# Como transformar HTML em imagem no servidor?

Tags: c#, conversão

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC com .Net Framework 4 no Visual Studio, onde preciso transformar uma string com código HTML em imagem **no lado do servidor**.

Tenho tentado usar [essa biblioteca](https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer), mas estou aberto a novas opções.

O código está assim:

```
Image m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(400, 600);
PointF point = new PointF(0, 0);
SizeF maxSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF(500, 500);
TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.WinForms.HtmlRender.RenderToImage(m_Bitmap, "<html><body><p>This is a shitty html code</p><p>This is another html line</p></body>");

m_Bitmap.Save(@"C:\Test.bmp");
```

Baixei a biblioteca, mas não sei se estou usando a DLL correta, pois não encontrei uma opção para Asp.Net MVC.

```
HtmlRenderer 1.5.0.6\WinForms\NET40\HtmlRenderer.WinForms.dll
```

Comment: Por que precisaria uma opção para o ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: Cara, se essa do WinForms funcionasse no meu projeto estaria de boa pra mim...

Comment: Eu não entendo o funcionamento disto mas é estranho ser específico, deveria gerar uma imagem e ponto, não interessa onde você deve usar. Eu já questiono a qualidade dela por causa disto. Tem outros que funcionam? Tem específica para Mono que funciona? Ou p/ PDF? Aqui parece ser o certo: http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Image%20generation

Comment: Tente com este se o queres deve ser tratado do lado do cliente:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html
Se for do lado do servidor, talvez esta resposta te ajude, pois me ajudou no passado:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui uma grande ajuda com [esse link](http://webstackoflove.com/convert-html-to-image-using-premailer-and-htmlrenderer-in-asp-net-mvc/), e percebi que estava usando a biblioteca da meneira errada.

Eu havia baixado a DLL, colocado em uma pasta no projeto e adicionado uma referencia. Mas não funcionou muito bem assim, então instalei a biblioteca [via Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.Core/), e voilà!

Logo depois instalei [essa outra biblioteca](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PreMailer.Net) da mesma forma, seguindo o tutorial.

O código ficou assim:

```
var result = PreMailer.Net.PreMailer.MoveCssInline(html: html, 
                                                    removeStyleElements: false, 
                                                    ignoreElements: null, 
                                                    stripIdAndClassAttributes: false);

var image = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.WinForms.HtmlRender.RenderToImage(result.Html, new Size(390, 290));
```

Então eu posso fazer qualquer coisa com `image`, desde salvar em disco até trabalhar em `MemoryStream`...

Answer (score 7):

Dentro do *contexto* de projetos é **normal** a necessidade de se gerar **relatórios**, basicamente a medida em que o nível de detalhamento aumenta, a complexidade do relatório também aumenta. Daí a necessidade de incorporar imagens a textos, ou tabelas a imagens ou até mesmo todos juntos.

Por isso, vou sugerir como resposta a transformação do HTML para PDF, pois assim o código pode ser reaproveitável e sem a necessidade de ter que ficar trocando de biblioteca ou plugins, além do fato de que o PDF é em sua maior parte composto de [Post Script](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript).

Em outras palavras, o PDF é basicamente uma Imagem.

Existe uma biblioteca *free* chamada [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), já utilizei e resolveu um problema semelhante que tive.

**Exemplo de como utilizar**:

```c#
//Cria um array de bytes para salvar os dados do PDF
Byte[] bytes;
//Para evitar preocupação com alocação de memória e etc...
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    //Cria um documento abstrato
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        //Cria um escritor para bindar os dados no documento abstrato
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)) {
            //Abre o documento abstrato
            doc.Open();
            //Insere o HTML e o CSS como string ou como variável
            var example_html = @"<body><p>This is a shitty html code</p><p>This is another html line</p></body>";
            var example_css = @"CSS AQUI";
            //Converte as strings do HTML e CSS
            using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css))) {
                using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html))) {
                    //Faz o Parse do HTML
                  iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                }
            }
          //Fecha o documento
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
    //Fecha MemoryStream e joga dentro do array de bytes
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
//Transfere o array para o disco
var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "download.pdf");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, bytes);
```

Agora se o que você realmente quer é uma imagem, simplesmente faça:

```c#
//Realiza uma iteração para cada página
for(int i=0;i< pdfdocument.Pages.Count;i++)  
{
  //Salva a página como imagem
  System.Drawing.Image image= pdfdocument.SaveAsImage(i, 96, 96);  
  image.Save(string.Format("ImagePage{0}.png", i), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);  
}
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Comment: +1 para ganhar a permissão de comentar, lembrando de ler os tópicos [ask] e [answer]

Comment: +1 pra ganhar permissão de comentar também, rsrsrs... Obrigado pela resposta meu amigo. Infelizmente tenho que fazer tudo do lado do servidor (vou editar a pergunta para acrescentar isso). Recebi uma ajuda aqui e postarei mais tarde a solução encontrada.

Comment: Creio que não faltou muito para você poder realmente dar uma resposta, você poderia trazer um pouco do conteúdo desses links para a publicação que acredito que já poderia ser considerada. Do jeito que está vai acabar sendo removida ou transformada em comentário.

Comment: Chance concedida :)

Comment: Só uma pergunta, nesse trecho de código você está gerando um `pdf` ou `imagem`?

Comment: Levando em consideração que o PDF é basicamente uma imagem, a resposta seria: **os dois**. De qualquer forma editei a resposta para que abranja os dois casos.